# How to do time "HH:mm" comparison in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, datetime, if-statement

Apparently my code is like this and it is now working. I think the logic is already there. the $openTime and $closeTime is read from csv using import-csv in "HH:mm" form.

```
$openTime = $ip.openTime
$closeTime = $ip.closeTime
$time = Get-Date -UFormat "%R"

if (($time -ge $openTime) -and ($time -le $closeTime)) {
        Write-Host "Store is Open!" -ForegroundColor Green
}else{
        Write-Host "Store is outside open hours!" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: So what _isn't_ working?

Comment: So, seeing as @mklement0 has just very cleverly suggested that this is working code I had another look and learned yet another thing about powershell.  It compares time strings!  No need for DateTime objects.  This should be working code.  Much appreciated mklement0 for yet another lesson.  Probably your most concise yet :)

Comment: The not working is the time format read from csv. I think the code is not working to compare time format in "H:mm", mine is working with "HH:mm"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working with the time are imported from csv, make sure the time format in the csv file is in "HH:mm"

Answer (score 0):

#### powershell 7

```
$csv = @"
store, openTime, closeTime
Wallmart, 08:00, 18:00
Ikea, 10:00, 20:30
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

Get-Date
$csv | ForEach-Object{
    [int]([datetime]::Now - [datetime]::Today).TotalMinutes -in (.{[int]$args[0][0]*60 + [int]$args[0][1]} $_.openTime.split(":"))..(.{[int]$args[0][0]*60 + [int]$args[0][1]} $_.closeTime.split(":")) ? "Store {0} is Open! " -f $_.store : "Store {0} is outside open hours!" -f $_.store
}
```

```
16 февраля 2021 г. 8:52:42
Store Wallmart is Open!
Store Ikea is outside open hours!
```

#### powershell 5

```
$csv = @"
store, openTime, closeTime
Wallmart, 08:00, 18:00
Ikea, 10:00, 20:30
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

Get-Date
$csv | ForEach-Object{
    ("Store {0} is outside open hours!", "Store {0} is Open! ")[[int]([datetime]::Now - [datetime]::Today).TotalMinutes -in (.{[int]$args[0][0]*60 + [int]$args[0][1]} $_.openTime.split(":"))..(.{[int]$args[0][0]*60 + [int]$args[0][1]} $_.closeTime.split(":"))] -f $_.store
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVFNS8QwEL3nV8yGHlptQlZBpCAsrK540D1Y8FCKxDbaaNqUJO0i3f3tNS0ou0eHgXm8@XrMtHonjK2EUqTQRoxjUNgebmCFkXWeiEG3okll7VGhtBUTRC9cqZobFwO7ThiLYTkF9PAluMdspi5YcskQXsEe1rrphXEbo2uytj1C98KRW@4EmrftYaPNHS8qsn37FIUbEHgL8fMkAAZ2AGlBd87KUsxyoNKdsQscw2nN1ucWgKMsk43Lw6z0K5zXmyfJk94BgWMm1SX/jmiqHVePsumcsEBkAyEd5vaAmw@bsdz72RWDczhll/kBglf6ex1qWyVdiBMcRZT@b8bfXY@H5EDep@T8BXQYxx8)

Answer (score 0):

I find it's much easier to work with date and times if I convert them to [DateTime] objects.  We can use the DateTime class method [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-5.0) to convert the time into [DateTime] objects for us.  This object will actually contain today's date as well as the time we supply, but for our purposes this is fine since the $time object also will be today's date.  For the current time ($time) just let `Get-Date` return to us a [DateTime] object that will represent the current date and time (now).  After that the rest of your code works as expected.  Hurray!

```
    # this $ip hashtable object just represents data similar to your csv import
    $ip = @{
        openTime = "09:00"
        closeTime = "21:00"
    }
    
    $openTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($ip.openTime, 'HH:mm', $null)
    $closeTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($ip.closeTime, 'HH:mm', $null)
    $time = Get-Date
    
    if (($time -ge $openTime) -and ($time -le $closeTime)) {
        Write-Host "Store is Open!" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Store is outside open hours!" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
```